# CSS comments are not working when they break up property names

Tags: html, css, styles, comments

I’m trying to use comments in CSS for special reasons, but it doesn't seem to be working. Essentially it’s something like

```
<style>
    body {co/*garbage*/lo/*garbage*/r:bl/*garbage*/ue}
</style>
```

Obviously I want to just remove the `/*garbage*/`, but I can’t. I thought that in CSS you can comment things out with /* and */. Was I wrong?

Comment: `but it doesn't seem to be working` what's not working ? and using comment in the middle of property definition is not allowed

Comment: Ok, thanks I didnt know that using comment in the middle of property definition is not allowed

Comment: Is it allowed in C? Due to [the preprocessor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_preprocessor)?